# Metallic drip tray for fridge

Tags: electrical, refrigerator

The drip tray of my fridge broke down, which causes the water condensating in the fridge to drip on the compressor, which is not a good thing.
While waiting for the replacement part, I've replaced the drip tray with a can (which fulfills the same purpose, e.g. recovering the water from the fridge and evaporating it using the heat from the compressor).

However, all the drip trays available on the market are made of plastic, and not of metal. To me, using a metallic drip tray may not be an issue, but I may be overlooking some key parts regarding heat transfer in the cooling system or something. Hence my question: it the use of a metallic drip tray located above the compressor in a fridge potentially dangerous or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not stainless steel it might rust (or generically corrode for non-steel) sooner than plastic would break. Manufacturing-wise, the plastic part is no doubt less expensive to make.